# Operator-sdk issue

Tags: kubernetes, operator-sdk

I had an Operator, and deploy it on 3 different namespaces in the same cluster, then I got the following errors. I could not figure out what's wrong here and how to fix them? Any idea for that?

```
E1111 15:02:48.398838       1 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.6/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1alpha1.Bird: Birds.xxxx.com is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:aaaa-test:default" cannot list resource "Birds" in API group "xxxx.com" in the namespace "aaaa-test"
E1111 15:02:50.193666       1 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.6/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1alpha1.Bird: Birds.xxxx.com is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:aaaa-test:default" cannot list resource "Birds" in API group "xxxx.com" in the namespace "aaaa-test"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message means that the service account you use for your Operator does misses certain permissions. You need to add Role which has permissions to `list` the resource `Birds`.

Something like this:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: operator
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - xxxx.com
    resources:
      - birds
    verbs:
      - list
```

Needless to say, you also need to add `ClusterRoleBinding`.

Please check more details in the example: [Build Your Operator with the Right Tool](https://github.com/leszko/build-your-operator).